# Python multiprocessing pool does not work when importing custom classes in the script

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I have a simple Python script which runs a parallel pool:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def square(x):
    return x**2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(4)
    results=pool.map(square,range(1,20))
```

It works fine and as expected. However, if I import any simple custom class, such as the code below, it doesn't work any more. I start the script execution, but the script does not terminate. This is weird, as I do not use the imported class.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from Person import Person

def square(x):
    return x**2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(4)
    results=pool.map(square,range(1,20))
```

The class *Person* is very simple:

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, id):
    self.id = id
```

What is the reason for this behavior and how can I fix it?

EDIT: I am using Windows 10

Comment: Which OS (so we know if multiprocessing spawns or forks)?

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Comment: Code works on linux (forking). Windows does more pickling of state for the subprocess, but I don't have a windows around to test. Good luck!

Comment: It got me thinking, have you tried this specific example? I set mp on my linux machine to "spawn" and it sill worked.